# Random requests slowdowns in stored procedure execution with SqlConnection in ASP Net Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, sqlclient

**UPDATE:**

Data access delay is discarded. I am logging the GetAllProductsAsync call execution time and the elapsed time is stable. Issue must be in somewhere else.

---

I have an API that returns a list of products. The API get that from a services where a SQL Server stored procedure is executed using `System.Data.SqlClient` to be as performant as it can.

The stored procedure execution runs in less than 6 ms and the API responses in 20 ms average. If I run it locally and send several `GET` requests using Postman (Runner), the response time is almost the same in every request.

[image: Test config]

But then, I deployed it to a production server (IIS) and performed the same test with Postman. The production server is idle because it's new and it's accessed via LAN so there is no overhead.

The results I got are pretty unstable. The pattern in a 1000 request test is always the same. One or two requests are completed in 20 ms, then a couple more in 500 ms. There is a huge difference between each other.

[image]

I started a trace using SQL Server Profiler to check if the slowdown is due to the database. But every execution in the database takes the same time, no more than 2 ms.

Another thing that seems weird, is that every database execution is performed with the same SPID. It looks that the connection it is always the same, despite the service is transient and the connection disposed.

I think there might be some locking between requests and the SQL connection. What can it be?

I also tried to retrieve the data using async methods, but the result was the same. Tried Dapper too, same result.

This is my code:

Controller:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ProductService _productService;

        public ProductController(ProductService productService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts()
        {
            var result = await _productService.GetAllProductsAsync();
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Service (async and sync methods):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ProductService
{
    private string connectionString = "xxxxx";

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var productList = new List<Product>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllProducts", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                productList.Add(new Product
                {
                    Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                    Name = (string)reader["Name"],
                    From = (DateTime)reader["From"],
                    To = (DateTime)reader["To"]
                });
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        return productList;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()
    {
        var productList = new List<Product>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllEmployees", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            await con.OpenAsync();
            SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                productList.Add(new Product
                {
                    Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                    Name = (string)reader["Name"],
                    From = (DateTime)reader["From"],
                    To = (DateTime)reader["To"]
                });
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        return productList;
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ProductService>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If the performance issue is not in the database then it's in the web component somewhere. In this situation I would straight away blame parameter sniffing in the database but it appears you have ruled that out as an issue.

Comment: Just to throw my 5 cents, since I don't believe it's possible to point the issue straight away given the information provided. Since you are making 1k requests with no delay I suspect that at some point there is a request waiting for a connection from the connection pool.One thing you may try is to reduce the number of requests starting from 50 for example and see if the issue disappear with fewer requests. Further read on connection pools - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Data access delay is discarded. I am logging the GetAllProductsAsync call execution time and the elapsed time is stable. Issue must be in somewhere else.